# Can I replace my 700C x 38mm tyres for 700Cx23mm or 25 ones?

Tags: tire, road

what would be my possibilities if I cant?

Comment: Depends on your rim size. If the internal width is more than 20mm I'd not recommend such narrow tyres. What kind of bike is it and what kind of riding are you doing? The trend these days is to go wider, not narrower.

Comment: The duplicate concentrates most on compatibility, but in addition a bike designed for 38mm tires will probably be awful to ride with 23s.